# Considering correlation of independent variables in regression model

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression

I have one dependent variable `C` and four independent variables:

- `S`
- `SD`
- `TPA`
- `VPT`

The correlation matrix between them is the following

```
    TPA     VPT      S
TPA -       -       -
VPT -0.37   -       -
S   0.04    0.00    -
SD  0.05    -0.04   0.01
```

`TPA`and `VPT` have a moderate negative linear relationship.

Now I want to create a regression model:

```
C ~ S + SD + VPT + TPA
```

Does it makes sense to consider the correlation between `VPT` and `TPA` in the model? If so, what should I add to it to consider the correlation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question goes to two issues: Collinearity and interactions/mediation.

Collinearity is a problem in regression. However, it is best assessed with condition indexes, not correlation matrices. If you are using `R` you can get these in the `perturb` package; if you are using `SAS` you can get them with the /collin option. Although I said that correlations aren't the best way to look at collinearity, I don't think this will be a problem here.

There is nothing to add to the model to "consider the correlation". However, when IVs are correlated, they can mediate each other, so you may want to compare models with both terms to ones with only one; then, you may be able to say that one IV mediates the other.

Also, IVs may have interactions, which *is* something to add to the model, but even uncorrelated variables can interact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a library to check if to check if IVs mediate each other? Or is the only way to find out by comparing different models?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to compare the models - that's what any package would do, anyway

Comment: Do you have an example, @PeterFlom, of when uncorrelated variables can interact?

Comment: @Erosennin  Yes.  In predicting HIV risk, there is an interaction between sex (male, female, other) and sexuality (gay, straight, other).  Another is that, in predicting income, there is an interaction between race and sex (the gap between blacks and whites is much larger for men than for women).